PrismaAdapter can't build
My code working in "npm run dev" mode, but when I want to build my project I take this error:

 ./node_modules/next-auth/src/core/lib/assert.ts:134:27

Type error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Adapter'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Adapter'.
132 |       "useVerificationToken",
133 |       "getUserByEmail",
134 |     ].filter((method) => !adapter[method])
|                           ^
135 |
136 |     if (missingMethods.length) {
137 |       return new MissingAdapterMethods(

I think that problem in this part:
    import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
    import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
    import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
    import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
    import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';

    import prisma from '@/app/libs/prismadb';
    import {Adapter} from "next-auth/adapters";

    export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
        adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma) ,

but type that PrismaApadter return - Adapter:
 export function PrismaAdapter(     p: PrismaClient): Adapter`

And "adapter" take Adapter too:
AuthOptions. adapter?: Adapter | undefined

I already try change:
"NextAuthOptions"
to
"AuthOptions"
But it is not working..
I tried to specify the type:
 adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma) as any  

 adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma as any)

That's all not working for me.

Welcome to stackoverflow, can you please follow the guide  so you can have the latest version of Auth.js, one other thing to mention is that you are importing PrismaAdapter from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter", in the recent version (V5), adapters are imported from @auth/adapter-name instead of `@next-auth/adapter-name.
